# how to use *ngFor in angular for Multiple values

Tags: angular

How to use *ngFor for multiple values in Angular?
I want to know the full description of *ngFor usage in Angular, 
I tried this:

*ngFor="let data of datas track by $index"

Comment: Welcome.  This is impossible to answer without more information.  Please see [ask], especially how to create an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Syntax from the angular io:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>
```

[link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)